# Create a temporary file and open it in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, temporary-files

Let say I have a database with several products. I'm making a page to create printable export of that database. On the page the user can setup the export depending on his needs. For example, choosing what categories of products he want to exclude from it, how he want it to be sorted and so on.
He then click on a button making an ajax call with the chosen settings to a php script making the sql request and everything.

From there I would like to generate a temporary html page to visualize the result and open it in a new tab to be printed. But once it is done, I don't need it anymore. I could write the html file from my php script and make my ajax call to open the new file on another tab but that would create a new file everytime and take a lot of space.

What is the best way to achieve that ? The main problem is that my php script result in a very long string that can't be send in the url. tmpfile() don't allow me to open the created file in a new tab as it is deleted at the end of the script.

I tried using tempnam() like this :

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("../tmp/",$_SESSION['loggedUser']);
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, "long string being my html code");
fclose($handle);

$success = true;
$return_arr = array($success,$tmpfname);
```

And my ajax call :

```
$.post('../php/export_script.php',{:settings},function(data){
    response = JSON.parse(data);
    if (response[0] == true) {
        var win = window.open('../landing.php?file='+response[1], '_blank');
        if (win) {
            win.focus();
        } else {
            alert("Browser blocked the opening of the file.");
        }
    }else{
        alert(response[1]);
    }
});
```

So that open the landing.php page that is like so :

```
<div id="content">
        <?php 
            $handle = $_GET['handle'];
            $fileData = @file_get_contents($handle);

            echo $fileData
        ?>
</div>
```

But that open the new tab with the clear path of the file in the url like this

> "https://mywebsite.com/landing.php?file=/home/myserver/myproject/tmp/userV4rIkE"

That looks unsafe to me, showing some clear server infos to the user. Is there a better way to achieve this ? I though about just creating a normal file in my tmp folder generating a random name with timestamp + user session code and setting up a way for my server to empty that folder every once in a while.

Comment: You don't need (and probably don't want) to create a new file. Just dynamically generate the page. _What is the best way to achieve that ?_ is opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent page, you can use javascript to create a new page, which gives you a way to write data into that new page - so just write the HTML from the parent into the new page.  It does not need any URL at all (about:blank) should work fine.

```
const handle = window.open();
if (handle) {
  // write HTML to child.
}
```

Comment: It's actually replacing the current page with a blank one. But I can't make it work in a new tab. I need the original page to stay open so the user want to tweak some settings and make a second export he can just go back to the original tab. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yep - you can read all the options here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp